# Can anyone tell me how to create a dockerrun.aws.json for this multicontainer docker microservices app in AWS EB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two microservices images, a Go Rest API and a React frontend which are both inside my AWS ECR. I'll be using Elastic Beanstalk. Now since I believe they're on same machine so I configured the React app to fetch data from the API on localhost:8080. Below are the Dockerfiles for both. They worked in my dev environment so I pushed them to my ECR.

Dockerfile for Golang Rest API

```
FROM golang
ADD . /go/src/vsts/project/gorestapi
WORKDIR /go/src/vsts/project/gorestapi
RUN go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
RUN dep ensure
RUN go install .
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/gorestapi
EXPOSE 8080
```

Dockerfile for React Frontend App

```
FROM node:8.4.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN npm i -g serve
CMD serve -s build/app -p 3000
EXPOSE 3000
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

I don't know if volume still needs to be declared, or the mountpoints, all I know is I need to put there the version of the dockerrun json to v2 and the name, image and portsmapping in container Definition. Most of the samples are confusing enough since none of them shows an app from private repo and they have those volumes, mountpoints, links, that I don't really understand how to use. I tried the one below but it did not work

Edit: (I changed Dockerrun.aws.json expecting Volume Host SourcePath to be the path in my machine. Please correct if I'm wrong)

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "webapp",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/webapp"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "gorestapi",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/gorestapi"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "gorestapi",
      "image": "<acctId>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/gorestapi:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "webapp"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "gorestapi",
          "containerPath": "/go/src/vsts/project/gorestapi"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "webapp",
      "image": "<acctId>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/webapp:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 256,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "webapp",
          "containerPath": "/usr/src/app"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Did I specify the correct values for the paths?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you still need to define the volumes and their mount points if you want to use them. Here is a more comprehensive guide in my opinion with regards to setting up a multi-container environment, straight out of the official docs plus they have a private repository section. Hoping that helps >> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun
Also, consider looking into EC2 Container Service (ECS), however, Elastic Beanstalk does use it in the background to run multi-container environments but could be easier to run them directly on ECS.

Comment: what should I specify in the volume's sourcepath? the name of the folder where the source of that image is located? or the build folder? or the whole project? Also the mountpoints' containerpath, which is it? I have tried it before with the volumes and mountpoints but deploy fails

Comment: The volume source path is the absolute path of the folder on the host that you want to mount to a given container path (folder inside the container). I'd be interested to see the error log when the deployment fails.

Comment: I'm currently figuring out how to see the error logs, but please look at the edit above